# AJAX Javascript Counter Performance Issue setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have an ajax call to a flask endpoint that makes an REST call to the google maps API, gets a date as a response, and passes it to an ajax success function that generates a counter. When the counter gets to 0 it's supposed to repeat the call to the flask endpoint and generate a new counter based on the information that gets returned. I've got this working but the counter updates too slowly, so there is definitely some flaw in my logic, which I believe to be my usage of the set interval function but I am new to Javascript and not sure. I noticed it also loops the api call 7-20 times before it actually updates the counter, and so the counter just displays in the negative until it does so

```
function updateRoute() {

$.ajax({
    url: '/_calculateRoute',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        var countDownDate = new Date(resp).getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function () {
                var now = new Date().getTime();

                var distance = countDownDate - now;

                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
                    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                if (distance < 0) {
                    // When the timer runs out have ajax make a request back to the /test route to return the next train time.
                    clearInterval(x); 
                    updateRoute();

                }
            },

            1000);

    }

});
}
```

And then the Flask endpoint looks like:

```
@app.route('/_calculateRoute')
def calculate_route():

try:
    address = Address.query.filter_by(active=True).first()
    print(address.source)
    gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='APIKEY')
    now = datetime.now()
    directions = gmaps.directions(address.source,
                                  address.destination,
                                  mode="transit",
                                  departure_time=now)

    departure_time = directions[0]['legs'][0]['departure_time']['text']

    # Convert departure_time list into a string datetime
    time = format_time(departure_time)

    return time

except googlemaps.exceptions.TransportError:
    return "Max retries exceeded with url"
```

Am I using setInterval and clearInterval incorrectly? What can I do to speed up the call and keep it from looping like it does? I'm also curious if in an instance like this when you have an external API call does it make more sense to query the api and store the details in the database before passing it back to the front end? I apologize for the long winded question. I am a rather new developer with lots of questions :) Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use of `setInterval` and `clearInterval ` looks to be correct. I would suspect data, not code, to be the culprit.

Comment: Check that `new Date(resp)` returns what you expect.

Comment: It does infact return the correct data as the counter does work. The problem happens when the timer runs to 0 and it has to recalculate. It does recalculate successfully but continuously repeats the call far too many times before it does

Comment: Try putting a console.log() immediately inside that updateRoute() method and see how often it prints

Comment: Trying that now

Comment: Symptoms suggest that, second time around, `countDownDate - now` immediately returns a negative number. If so, then `resp` has not advanced, or not advanced sufficiently, to exceed `now`.

Comment: Ahh okay thats a good point. I'm going to do some debugging today to see why thats happening